# Pynput breaks the terminal in linux when trying to get key pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu-20.04, pynput

I have writing the following code to get key pressed by the user:

```py
class Key:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    # Define the function that will be called when a key is pressed.
    def on_press(self, key: KeyType) -> None:
        pass
    
    # Define the function that will be called when a key is released.
    def on_release(self, key: KeyType, queue: Queue, listener: Listener) -> None:
        try:
            # Put the character key in the queue.
            queue.put(key.char)

            # Stop the listener
            listener.stop()
        
        except AttributeError:
            # Put non-character keys in the queue.
            queue.put(key.name)

            # Stop the listener
            listener.stop()

    def get_key(self, prompt_string: str) -> str:
        '''
        Prompts the user for a key.
        
        Args:
            prompt_string (str): A string representing the prompt to display to the user
            
        Returns:
            key (str): A key which the user pressed

        Examples:
            To prompt the user for a key and print the key that was pressed, use:

            >>> key = get_key("Press a key: ")
            >>> print("You pressed:", key)
        '''
        
        # Create a new queue object to hold the key value.
        key_queue = Queue()
        
        # Start a keyboard listener with the on_press and on_release functions.
        # Use a lambda function to pass the queue object to the on_release function.
        with Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release=lambda key: self.on_release(key, queue=key_queue, listener=listener)) as listener:
            # Print the prompt string to the console.
            # Use flush=True to ensure that the message is printed immediately.
            # Use end='' to make sure that the next print statement is on the same line.
            print(prompt_string, end='', flush=True)
            
            # Initialize the key value to None.
            key = None
            
            # Keep looping until a key value has been retrieved from the queue.
            while key is None:
                key = key_queue.get()
            
            # Return the key value to the calling function.
            return key
```

I call the above code in a separate file after which I ask the user for a input using the `input()` function.

```py
# Get key to be autoclicked from user by calling get_key function with a prompt message.
button = key.get_key(f"{INPUT_COLOR}Key to be autoclicked (press any key): {RESET}")
# Print the button that the user has pressed.
print(USER_INPUT_COLOR + button + RESET)
            
# Get delay between key presses in seconds from user by calling get_input function with a prompt message.
delay = float(input(f"{INPUT_COLOR}Delay between key presses (in seconds): {USER_INPUT_COLOR}"))
print(f"{RESET}", end="")
```

But when the above code is executed I can press a button to enter a key for the button input but for the delay input when try to enter a float value like '0.1', it doesn't show anything that I am typing. Furthermore when I press enter after typing '0.1' it gives this error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'mqe0.1'`
or other times the error changes to this: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'kqer0.1'`.

After this the program naturally exists but I find that the terminal seems to be broken because whatever I type seems to not be displayed but it is there because when I enter the terminal responds to whatever I typed but doesn't show it.

Some extra info:

- I have checked and made sure all my imports and correct.
- the `f'{INPUT_COLOR}'` and `f'{RESET}` are just constant values for ansi escape codes that I have defined in another file and they are not causing the issue.
- the distro for linux that I am using is Zorin OS 16 which is built on Ubuntu 20.04.
- I am running the above code in bash terminal, which is provided by default when I installed Zorin (this is a relatively new install).

What I have tried:
I tried adding a `listener.stop()` to the `listener` for getting key presses but that doesn't change anything

Is this a problem with Pynput on linux or a problem with the code I have written?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this problem of the bash terminal breaking, where it doesn't respond to what you are typing can be fixed by executing the command `reset` in the terminal.

So for the app I just needed to add a `os.system("reset")` line after you are done using pynput to listen for key presses.

So the example code becomes:

```py
# Get key to be autoclicked from user by calling get_key function with a prompt message.
button = key.get_key(f"{INPUT_COLOR}Key to be autoclicked (press any key): {RESET}")
# Print the button that the user has pressed.
print(USER_INPUT_COLOR + button + RESET)

# Reset the terminal
os.system("reset")

# Get delay between key presses in seconds from user by calling get_input function with a prompt message.
delay = float(input(f"{INPUT_COLOR}Delay between key presses (in seconds): {USER_INPUT_COLOR}"))
print(f"{RESET}", end="")
```

This does erase the previous output from the terminal, but you can code a workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from `pynput` who capture key events in the terminal, but that disturb the normal behavior of the input() function.

You should add a delay so that the keyboard listener have enough time.

for example your code will become:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key as KeyType, Listener
from queue import Queue
import time

class Key:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def on_press(self, key):
        pass
    
    def on_release(self, key, queue, listener):
        try:
            queue.put(key.char)
            listener.stop()
        except AttributeError:
            queue.put(key.name)
            listener.stop()

    def get_key(self, prompt_string):
        key_queue = Queue()
        with Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release=lambda key: self.on_release(key, queue=key_queue, listener=listener)) as listener:
            print(prompt_string, end='', flush=True)
            key = None
            while key is None:
                key = key_queue.get()
            return key

key = Key()

button = key.get_key("Key to be autoclicked (press any key): ")
print(button)

time.sleep(0.1)

delay = float(input("Delay between key presses (in seconds): "))
print(delay)
```

If you still experience problem with the input, maybe try an alternative library for capturing key event.

Comment: I did also try this as a attempt to solve the problem but it doesn't seem to work, you can instead use 'reset' command to allow the user to type in the terminal again